# Google Search Console's keyword list: where did it go?

Tags: google-search-console

Google's Search Console used to have a section where it showed the main keywords for your site, as Google saw them. However, I can't find it anywhere now. The funny thing is, if you search Google itself for *"Google Search Console keyword list"*, the first result is:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/keywords

But if I visit that site, I get a 404.

Did I miss something? Did Google announce its removal somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content Keywords was removed from Google Search Console at the end of November.

- [Google Webmaster Central Blog - Saying goodbye to Content Keywords](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/saying-goodbye-to-content-keywords.html)

Comment: Good riddance.   I've never found any utility in that feature and we regularly got questions here asking why a certain keyword appeared in that report even though it never seemed to matter what was reported.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I thought it was quite useful and I miss it. It showed 'top pages' for keywords which was great. It was useful to show people using iframes/etc how their content wasn't being found properly. Also was useful to spot a hacked site since a number of bad keywords would show in the tool. Just because people misunderstand it doesn't mean it should have been removed :(

Comment: Except that I found the so-called keywords were pure unfiltered bull squirt. In all the years, I have not found any of the words to be used in search to find any site. It never made sense to me.